# A question about the group $[HZ,KU]$

Tags: homotopy-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology

I don't know if the following question is obvious, but can't figure it out.

I want to ask if it is known what $[HZ,KU]$ is? Here $KU$ is the complex $K$-theory.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324940/the-connective-k-theory-cohomology-of-eilenberg-maclane-spectra/325472#325472 and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327777/maps-from-mod-p-eilenberg-maclane-spectrum-to-connective-k-theory-spectrum

Comment: How is the connective K-theory of HZ related to its K-theory?

Comment: HZ is connective, so [HZ, KU] = [HZ, ku].

Comment: Your "certainly" is false. In fact what's true is that $[H\mathbb{Z},KU]=[HZ\wedge KU,KU]_{KU}$ where the latter group is computed **in the category of $KU$-modules**.

Answer (score 8):

Since KU is Anderson self dual there is a short exact sequence

$$
0 \to  Ext^1(KU_{-1}(H\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z})\to KU^0(H\mathbb{Z}) \to Hom(KU_0(H\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z})\to  0
$$

which shows that $[H\mathbb{Z},KU] = KU^0(H\mathbb{Z}) = 0$. Similarly we find that $KU^1(H\mathbb{Z}) = Ext^1(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Z})$. The latter
 is an uncountable $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space.

Comment: Dear @Thomas Nikolaus. What are the groups $KU_{j}(H\mathbb{Z})$?